# How to prohibit letter input, only allow numbers in Lua?

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

I need to determine if a string is in the format I want. What I want is `number|number|string`,such as `1|2|abc`. I tried this

```
if string.match( my_str,"[%d]|[1-2]|.") then 
  print("yes")
end
```

But I also got `yes` for `a1|2|abc`, which is not what I want. How to write regular expressions to ensure that the first few digits can only be numbers?

Comment: Do you want to match *numbers* (e.g. 123) or *digits* (e.g. 9)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank @Nick, I use `^%d|[1-2]|.+$` works fine.

Comment: You don't need the trailing `$`, `.+` will greedily match everything until the end anyways. Note that the crucial part here is the `^` anchor, which forces pattern matching to start at the beginning of the string (rather than anywhere in the string).